# Do I need to install "WD Apps Setup.exe"?

Tags: usb, installation, usb-storage

I just bought a `My Passport` 2TB Western Digital USB 3.0 portable hard drive [[link]](http://www.futureshop.ca/en-CA/product/wd-wd-my-passport-2tb-portable-external-usb-3-0-hard-drive-wdby8l0020bbk-nesn-black-wdby8l0020bbk-nesn/10180515.aspx), do I need to install "WD Apps Setup.exe"?

MORE: From checking `Device Manager`, my system does not appear to be USB 3.0. I see no mention of 3.0 in there. I mention this in case this install is related to USB 3.0.

Comment: No, you do not need to install the "WD Apps". And, no, it has nothing to do with USB 3.0. I suggest you look at the PDF that describes the WD Apps which is included on the drive, if you want to know more about the "WD Apps".